# Java: Collapsing short "if/else" with simple "return"s and trailing "throw" into a single "return"

Tags: java, syntax, type-inference, short-circuiting

Here is some code that is more or less a "daily" pattern:

```java
public static Value getValue() {    
    if ( cond1 ) {
        return val1;
    }
    if ( cond2 ) {
        return val2;
    }
    if ( cond3 ) {
        return val3;
    }
    throw new AnyException();
}
```

At the very first glance, it seems to be able to collapse into a single `return` statement preserving short-circuit computation like this:

```java
public static Value getValue() {    
    return cond1 ? val1 :
           cond2 ? val2 :
           cond3 ? val3 :
           throw new AnyException() // it could be a legal piece of code in Java
                                    // if the `throw` statement could be an expression
           ;
}
```

However, it's not legal, because `throw` is a statement keyword, not an expression. I've tried the following workaround using a generic method:

```java
// Exceptions.java
// Just pretend to let the compiler think it's not an exception statement
public static <T, E extends Throwable> T exception(E ex) throws E {
    throw ex;
}

...
// Return.java
public static Value getValue() {    
    return cond1 ? val1 :
           cond2 ? val2 :
           cond3 ? val3 :
           Exceptions.<Value, AnyException>exception(new AnyException());
}
```

The the last line in the `return` statement looks ugly because:

- verbose syntax and required type parameterization;
- a static import directive cannot be used here.

Is there an elegant way to make that code a little nicer? Thanks in advance.

(I still must use Java 6)

EDIT:

Well, three years later, this feature is suprisingly implemented for [C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-throw-expressions). I find it really useful and natural, and not complicated. Example:

```cs
public string GetFirstName()
{
    var parts = Name.Split(" ");
    return parts.Length > 0
        ? parts[0]
        : throw new InvalidOperationException("No name!");
}
```

Lucky C# guys.

Comment: Why you try to code so complicated?? code easy and clear. I don't see any advantage of your second example, but it will be hard to debug and maintain

Comment: @MaximShoustin but `?:` is easy and clear for short expressions too...

Comment: I mean `Wild card` and chaining code like `? : ? : `. Try to set braking point on `return`

Comment: @MaximShoustin yes, my intention to collapse into a single return kills the breakpoints. That's a good note, thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used `exception` outside the conditional operator, then type inference would do the right thing. Here, instead of specifying the type arguments, you can just downcast the result into `Value`, either locally for `exception()`:

```
return cond1 ? val1 :
       cond2 ? val2 :
       cond3 ? val3 :
       (Value)exception(new AnyException());
```

or globally, for the entire conditional expression:

```
return (Value) (
       cond1 ? val1 :
       cond2 ? val2 :
       cond3 ? val3 :
       exception(new AnyException()));
```

This is still not gold in terms of elegance, but I think it goes a long way. Note that in this case you can have a static import for `exception()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Marko, and pointing that I missed the type casts for the results. This is exactly what I want: shorten the code. However, what do you think for `public static <T, E extends Throwable> T exception(Class<T> type, E ex) throws E {` and then `exception(Value.class, new AnyException())` ? This has a micro-micro performance hit for passing an extra argument, but it can be neglected when it ends with throwing an exception. And one pro: in this case I can avoid type casting and let the `exception(...` to appear at the most left text column keeping the code formatting clean.

Comment: Ah, don't worry. The question in the comment above doesn't have matter anymore. Type casts aren't necessary for `(Object)`. So I prefer your 1st way. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you rearrange your lines and add another `if` statement, you can minimize the amount of lines while still having something that is readable.

```
if(!(cond1 || cond2 || cond3)) throw new AnyException();
return cond1 ? val1 :
       cond2 ? val2 :
       cond3 ? val3;
```

I must say that you are overcomplicating things though. Readable code is almost always better than really concise code. In your first example, I immediately see what you're trying to do. In your second example, I actually have to concentrate.

Comment: Readability is here all about routine: I personally use the conditional operator like this all the time, and I have to concentrate much *less* when reading the second example. That is because the second example has only one exit point, which is declared at the outset with a single `return`.

Comment: +1 or `if(!cond1 && !cond2 && !cond3)`  In this case the last `cond3` check should be redundant, it must be true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that this has a few problems: 1) the condNs must be always reflected in two places, and that makes the code much more complicated than what I expected: I wanted it to be as short as possible; 2) condN might stand for a function call.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to throw a generic exception without generics.

```
// Exceptions.java
// Just pretend to let the compiler think it's not an exception statement
public static <T> T exception(E ex, Class<T> tClass) {
    Thread.currentThread().stop(ex);
    return null;
}

...
// Return.java
public static Value getValue() {    
    return cond1 ? val1 :
           cond2 ? val2 :
           cond3 ? val3 :
           exception(new AnyException(), Value.class); // import static Exception
}
```

You can also use Unsafe.throwException(e);

Comment: This throws the exception sneakily, allowing you to throw checked exceptions without declaring them. I personally *like* that fact, and use the Generics-based Sneaky Throw idiom routinely, but OP may not :)

Comment: Actually, I think it's the best answer to OP's question: passing `Class<T>` as 2nd parameter to `exception` method is greay way to avoid explicit parameterization. So, with suggested in this answer signature one can simply invoke `exception(ex, Object.class)` which is shorter than parameterizing method invocation explicitly. `Thread.currentThread().stop(ex)` can be replaced with `throw ex` to avoid checked/unchecked problem mentioned by Marko Topolnik.

Comment: @Yura Then I'd have both variants: with the type marker argument and without, because in other contexts (outside of the conditional operator) the type can be cleanly inferred. But anyway, there is not that much mileage in using a type marker vs. a simple downcast. Clearly, the downcast will never fail :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yep, you're right - downcasting is also a quite good way to go

Answer (score 0):

```
int length = 1;
String s = "abc"

return (length == s.length())? length: length+1;
```

Short hand if else for return function.